How to put sum of dataframe column in certain cell of excel sheet?
I have multiple dataframes and for each of them I am creating a separate excel sheet. After I've done this, I want to add for each sheet the sum of a certain column.
I have tried to create a dictionary and in the for loop when I create the dataframes to add to the dictionary the name of the excel sheet and the sum of the column that I want.
Here is an example of what I have done :
for p in my_list:
   total = {}
   ...
   df[p] = pd.Dataframe(my_list)
   total[p] = df[p]['column'].sum()

.....

sheet['D32'] = total.get(sheet_name)


When i do this the total dictionary keeps updating at each iteration and in the end for each sheet in my excel file I get the same value corresponding to the last dataframe. Could you help me with a solution?

Aside: you shouldn't use "list" as a variable for your list. You are overwriting a built-in function. See further here.

You are initialising total inside the loop so it gets reinitialised at each iteration. Initialise it before the loop:
total = {}

for p in my_list:
   ...
   df[p] = pd.Dataframe(my_list)
   total[p] = df[p]['column'].sum()

.....

sheet['D32'] = total.get(sheet_name)

